# dynamic label names in GA event tracking?

Tags: ios, uitableview, event-handling, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a question regarding Google Analytics and event tracking in IOS. In my app I have a tableView (some of the code shown below) which the user selects different books in. I want to be able to track the most used book.

But how do you track a dynamic event ? In the Google analytics portal you have to specify the label name? But what if the label name can be pretty much anything? Do I really need to create 40 different events for all 40 different books being possible to select in the app ? Is it possible to track this in a good way ? Thx for all the help / Regards

the code I am talking about: **withLabel:self.getCurrentBookName** <--- can pretty much result in any book name.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)pTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellName = @"";
UITableViewCell *cell = nil; 

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    cellName = @"BookCell";
    cell = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];
    UILabel *bookField = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    bookField.text = [self getCurrentBookName];

    [self.tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"App Setting"
                        withAction:@"User selects book:"
                         withLabel:self.getCurrentBookName
                         withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are setting up the event looks correct to me.

From [Google's doco on event tracking with the iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/events):

```
[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                     withAction:@"buttonPress"
                      withLabel:buttonName
                      withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
```

Here, the `buttonName` can be anything, and this is basically what you have done with your book names.

From the Google Analytics webpage you can filter the events by category and then by action. This will give you a list of event labels with the specified category and action.

1. When you are in Google Analytics, go to Engagement > Events > Top Events
2. Select the Event Category (in your case, "App Setting")
3. Select the Event Action from the list (in your case, "User selects book:")
4. You now have a list of Event Labels (in your case, book names)